# Tesseract multiple output format

Tags: ocr, tesseract

**My context**

I'm using tesseract to extract text from an image.

I'm generating a *.tsv* to retrieve the extracted text and perform some regex on it and a *.pdf* to have a searchable pdf.

The way I do it is by calling tesseract 2 times:

- One asking for the .tsv
- One asking for the .pdf

But I feel like this is not very efficient (the same computations must be made two times)

**What I wish**

I wish to make my computations go faster. And my idea is to call tesseract only once but specifying two output formats

Is it possible? If so how?

Comment: Can you try `tesseract yourimage.tif out pdf tsv`?

Comment: Whooo, simple and efficient. If you wish post it as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try the command:

`tesseract yourimage.tif out pdf tsv`